# Adding an image in forcelayout

Tags: d3.js

I am getting error while adding a image in force layout. Please help me. I am using https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1212215 to implement the images on nodes, but is the modified d3.js but I am getting syntax error.

JSON file:

```
{
     "nodes": [
         {"name": "server1", "imagen": "images1.png"},
         {"name": "server2", "imagen": "images1.png"},
         {"name": "server3"},
         {"name": "server4"},
         {"name": "app1"},
         {"name": "app2"},
         {"name": "app3"},
         {"name": "db1"},
         {"name": "db2"},
         {"name": "db3"}
     ],

     "links": [
         {"source": 4, "target": 0 },
         {"source": 4, "target": 1 },
         {"source": 4, "target": 2 },
         {"source": 4, "target": 3 },
         {"source": 5, "target": 0 },
         {"source": 5, "target": 1 },
         {"source": 5, "target": 2 },
         {"source": 5, "target": 3 },
         {"source": 6, "target": 0 },
         {"source": 6, "target": 1 },
         {"source": 6, "target": 2 },
         {"source": 6, "target": 3 },
         {"source": 4, "target": 7 },
         {"source": 5, "target": 8 },
         {"source": 5, "target": 9 },
         {"source": 6, "target": 8 }
     ]
 }
```

Code:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
 .data(json.nodes)
 .enter().append("g")
 .attr("class", "node")
 .image("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.imagen });
 .call(force.drag);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an `<image>` element with the attribute `xlink:href`.

```
 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(json.nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

node.append("svg:image")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.imagen });
```

```js
var json = {
  "nodes": [{
    "name": "Myriel",
    "imagen": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_spiderman.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Napoleon",
    "imagen": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_wolverine.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Mlle.Baptistine",
    "imagen": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_thor.png"
  }, {
    "name": "Mme.Magloire",
    "imagen": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_hulk.png"
  }],
  "links": [{
    "source": 1,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": 2,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 8
  }, {
    "source": 2,
    "target": 3,
    "value": 8
  }]
};

var width = 960,
  height = 500

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .gravity(0.1)
  .charge(-500)
  .linkDistance(100)
  .size([width, height]);

force
  .nodes(json.nodes)
  .links(json.links)
  .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(json.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke","red");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(json.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .call(force.drag);

node.append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    return d.imagen;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return -25;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return -25;
  })
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("width", 50)
  .append("title")
  .text(function(d){ return d.name });

force.on("tick", function() {

  link
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });
  node
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

});
```

```css
.link {
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-opacity: 0.3;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Now the error is gone. But images are not appearing. Do i need to change anything in the code

Comment: Images(Pictures) are not appearing in the browser. My intention is displaying pictures with mouse over text names. So i am using https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1212215. So if any suggestions on this.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I am able to see the pictures in the snippet. Maybe it takes some time to load the images at your end. Added image tooltip texts now.

Comment: I am using firefox portable edition. I am seeing only lines not with images. Problem with the browser?

Comment: I verified in Firefox 47.0.2. Could see the images.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help

Comment: It is working for me and one more question how to add colors to the links and search function